# Reading Excel File with multiple worksheets into database

Tags: c#

I'm in a pickle here. I'm reading an excel file that has three worksheet using exceldatareader's dataset function. After reading the file I have a dataset that contains three tables, one for each worksheet.

Now I need to export this data row by row into two different sql tables. These tables have an auto incremental primary key and PK of Table A makes up the FK in TableB . I'm using a stored procedure with SCOPE_IDENTITY() to achieve that.

Each column in excel file is a variable in stored procedure so as I iterate the sheets row by row I can assign these variables and then send them through stored procedure.

Now the question is how do I iterate through this dataset and assign each row[col] to variable for my stored procedure.

Thanks for help.

### Update More Info:

1.Sheet 1 goes to TABLE 1 in sql
2.Sheet 2 goes to Table 2 in sql
3.Sheet 3 also goes to Table 2 in sql
4.Table 1 has 1 to many relationship to Table 2

Comment: You should show the relevant problematic code

Comment: I'm not sure what code to show here since I don't even know where to begin. I'm playing with foreach loops but that's not getting me anywhere

Comment: three sheets, two sql tables? where is the third one going?

Comment: the third sheet is going to table2. I'll add that to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some half-pseudocode boilerplate to start from:

```
var datatable = dataset.Tables[0];
using(var proc = connection.CreateCommand(...))
{
    proc.Parameters.Add("@firstcolumnname", SqlDbType.Int);
    foreach(DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
    {
        /* check for DbNull.Value if source column is nullable! */
        proc.Parameters["@firstcolumnname"].Value = dr["FirstColumnName"];

        proc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But this makes much sense only if you're doing some data processing inside the stored procedure. Otherwise this calls for a bulk insert, especially if you have lots (thousands) of rows in the excel sheets.

The one-to-many relation (foreign key) can be tricky, if you can control the order of inserts then simply start with the "one" table and then load the "many" table aftewards. Let the stored procedure match the key values, if they are not part of the Excel source data.

Whole different story if you are in a concurrent multi-user environment and the tables are accessed and written to, while you load. Then you'd have to add transactions to preserve referential integrety throughout the process.

Comment: Thank You. i'll play with this and report back.